# Custom control does not update background color Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have created a custom control that i want to change color after a click. I can successfully load it, but once I run my function and want to change the color, nothing happens. When i try to do it with a regular element (button, label) it works.

Custom control (that is a Grid with a simple label inside):

```
public partial class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Item), typeof(Item), typeof(CustomGrid), propertyChanged: ItemChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsAnonymousSubColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomGrid), propertyChanged: CustomColorChanged);

    public Color CustomColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(CustomColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomColorProperty, value); }
    }

    static void CustomColorChanged (object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var x = bindable as CustomGrid;

        if (x.Item != null)
        {
             x.myLabelInMyXaml.BackgroundColor = x.CustomColor;
        }
    }

    static void ItemChanged (object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var x = bindable as CustomGrid;
    }

    public Item Item
    {
        get { return (Item) GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public CustomGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Here is my xaml, here i bind it to the viewmodel color code (binding works well on other elements, even if i try it inside the same stacklayout).

```
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                             Padding="0,10,0,0"
                                 VerticalOptions = "StartAndExpand" 
                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding newsService.FeedList}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>

                                <controls:CustomGrid Item ="{Binding .}"
                                               CustomColor = "{Binding BindingContext.CustomColorViewModel, Source={x:Reference ParentView}}" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private Color _CustomColorViewModel;
    public Color CustomColorViewModel
    {
        get { return _CustomColorViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _CustomColorViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CustomColorViewModel");
        }
    }
```

And i change it after loading it:

```
public void ChangeColor ()
{
    CustomColorViewModel = Color.Red;
}
```

XAML of custom control:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Neutral.Controls"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         xmlns:fftransformations="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Transformations;assembly=FFImageLoading.Transformations"
         xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
         x:Name="ParentView"
         x:Class="Project.Controls.CustomGrid">


         <Label x:Name = "myLabelInMyXaml" BackgroundColor = "{Binding CustomColorViewModel}"/>


 </Grid>
```

But the custom control background color does not change. It works when i initially load, but not when i try to update it. Note that i have no issue with other elements, only this custom control.

Not sure why it does not update the color.

Comment: Can you post XAML of `CustomGrid` , most probably you have to do x.BackgroundColor=newColor in `CustomColorChanged ` and you dont need x:Refernce Parentview

Comment: updated with xaml code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you used `CustomColor` property in `stacklayout`, but you add the `IsAnonymousSubColor` property in your `CustomColor` background code.

I change your `CustomColor` background code like following format(Just test function to change the color).

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomGrid : Grid
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty CustomColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomGrid), propertyChanged: CustomColorChanged);

        public Color CustomColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(CustomColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CustomColorProperty, value); }
        }

        static void CustomColorChanged(object bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var x = bindable as CustomGrid;
            x.myLabelInMyXaml.BackgroundColor = x.CustomColor;

        }



        public CustomGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: Do u add this element inside a stacklayout list? It seems to work when i bind it to an element that is outside of a stacklayout itemssource list.

Comment: I added it in the `StackLayout`, it worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the issue is:

```
x.myLabelInMyXaml.BackgroundColor = x.CustomColor;
```

Change it to:

```
x.myLabelInMyXaml.BackgroundColor = (Color) newValue;
```

Comment: Hmm does not seem to change anything. Same issue

Comment: thx! seems to work well now. accepted ur answer. i also created a new thread if ur interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253745/how-to-show-a-video-in-each-row-in-a-stacklayout-listview-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have an issue with the binding context.

Hard to say without seeing all of the code in context.

First of all, why are you calling a property a view model? The name doesn't really matter, but it is confusing as a property is not a view model, and without seeing the class that that property is in, it is hard to say what is going on here.

My suspicion is that the issue is here:

```
<controls:CustomGrid Item ="{Binding .}"
                     CustomColor = "{Binding BindingContext.CustomColorViewModel, Source={x:Reference ParentView}}" />
```

I think your binding code for the CustomColor should instead be (assuming your parent view is really named `ParentView`):

```
CustomColor = "{Binding Source={x:Reference ParentView}, Path=BindingContext.CustomColorViewModel}"
```

But again that is based on missing some vital code/information, but hopefully will at least move you in the right direction, if not be the solution.

Comment: Tried this but with no success. Funny enough, it works if i move the element outside of the stacklayout iemssource list (with the same binding).

Comment: Is there an element named "ParentView" in  your XAML? It may be defaulting to the true parent view, so when your control is outside of the stacklayout, the parent view may be different. Try naming your content page "ParentView" with <ContentPage x:Name="ParentView" ... > , or it may be better to use a different name that ParentView if ParentView is used elsewhere. (this is why I said there is missing information to know if my solution would work or not.. I have no idea what ParentView is in this context). I did test that my answer works if the ContentPage is named "ParentView".

Comment: if u put it inside a stacklayout list as well? for me it only seem to work when i have it outside. the page i am working with is a contentview page, and i have the ParentView there.