# How to show a video in each row in a stacklayout / listview [Xamarin.Forms]?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using the plugin https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager where they have video support.

I successfully use it and am able to play a video, but now that i try to display multiple videos in a stacklayout list (similiar to a instagram or twitter feed), then we are running into issues.

So i bind each item in the list to a unique video URL, but once i scroll through the list, then the video appears 1st on top of eachother/the same video is reused on all rows, even though it should only be in 1.

```
 <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FlowList}">
       <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                  <StackLayout>
                      <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                      <mm:VideoView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      AutoPlay="True"
                      Source="{Binding Video}"
                      VideoAspect="AspectFill"/>

                 </StackLayout>
             </DataTemplate>
         </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
  </StackLayout>
```

So the Title for each row loads well, indicating that there is nothing wrong going on with the binding etc. The issue as explained above is that the same 1 video appears on all rows, even though it should only be on one and each row has a unique video attached to it, same as the "Title" for the label.

Anyone know if there is a limitation/bug with the MediaManager plugin and if there is any other suggestion/route to go here?

Comment: As I know, for now, the `MediaPlayer` do not support to play the multiples videos in a single page.

Comment: Do you know of any other project / github reference that supports this?

Comment: I forked the Github of `danylovolokh`. https://github.com/WendyZang/VideoPlayerManager He provided VideoPlayerManager which consists from two libraries, Video-Player-Manager and List-Visibility-Utils. It could play multiple videos. You could check the link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper HeightRequest to your VideoView otherwise it create problem if you did't set it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height request for video viewer that will resolve your issue.
By adding from Xaml or xaml.cs